# Как подключится к localhost ПК из Android-приложения?

Tags: java, android, localhost, rest

Код Android-клиента:

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.106:8080/RestApp2_war_exploded/rs/hello");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
Log.e("TAG", "metka 1");
urlConnection.connect();
Log.e("TAG", "metka 2");
  //здесь обрабтчик
catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e("TAG", "Io exc " + e);
}
```

Сервер на Java и возвращает обычную строку. В браузере работает.

До второй метки код так и не доходит. Лог:

> 03-15 17:59:18.122 23717-23934/com.ka.restapp1 E/TAG: metka 1
>
> 03-15 17:59:23.240 23717-23934/com.ka.restapp1 E/TAG: Io exc
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.106
>   (port 8080) after 5000ms

Тестирую на реальном аппарате. Правильно ли я указываю хост **192.168.0.106**?

И еще маленький вопрос: то, что я сейчас делаю, и называется RESTful клиентом?

Comment: Заходит с браузера компьютера или браузера мобильного устройства? Если компьютер и мобильное устройство находятся в одной сети,  ip-адрес указан правильный, то может быть, что фаерволл на компьютере блокирует порт 8080

Comment: браузер компьютера. С браузера моб. устройства выдает ошибку `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`

Comment: Спасиб большое, дело в фаерволе. Скажите, это и есть REST клиент?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По описанному выше, нельзя точно сказать, Rest у Вас, или нет.

Выполняются ли у Вас основные принципы Rest:

1. Явное использование HTTP-методов.
2. Несохранение состояния.
3. Предоставление URI, аналогичных структуре каталогов.
4. Передача данных в XML, JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) или в обоих форматах?

Хорошая статья для ознакомления: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/ws-restfu/